# Recursive Directory Searching For Filenames

Tags: vba, file-system

**Purpose:**

Given a target folder, and a list of target sub-strings, determine if the folder (or any of its' sub-folders) has a filename which contains any of the target substrings.

---

**N.B.** This class uses Early-Binding and requires a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`

---

**Properties:**

> ```
>     RootFolder As Folder
>     StringsToMatch As Dictionary
>     FoldersRecursed As Dictionary
>     matchFound As Boolean
>     MatchedFilePath As String
> ```

---

**Exposed Methods:**

> ```
> AddTargetSubstring()
> ClearTargetSubstrings()
> SearchFolderForMatch()
> ```

---

**Private Methods:**

> ```
> RecurseFolderForMatch()
> NameContainsAnyTargetSubstring()
> ```

---

**Program Flow:**

Essentially all of the work is done by `RecurseFolderForMatch`, which works thus:

> '/ Search all filenames in the folder for a substring match
>   '/ If there is no match, iterate sub-folders
>   '/ For each subfolder, call RecurseFolderForMatch
>   '/ Short-Circuit if This.MatchFound gets set to True

---

**Example Usage:**

```
Set folderSearch = New CLS_Search_Folder
With folderSearch
    .RootFolder = targetFolder
    .AddTargetSubstring "Signed Updated Client Agreement"
    .AddTargetSubstring "Signed Joint Client Agreement"
    .AddTargetSubstring "Signed Client Agreement"
    .AddTargetSubstring "Signed TOB"
    .AddTargetSubstring "Signed Terms Of Business"
    .SearchFolderForMatch

    If .FoundMatch Then

        ...
```

---

### `CLS_Search_Folder`

```
    Option Explicit

    Private Type SearchProperties
        RootFolder As Folder
        StringsToMatch As Dictionary
        MatchFound As Boolean
        MatchedFilePath As String
    End Type
    Private this As SearchProperties

    Public Property Get FoundMatch() As Boolean
        FoundMatch = this.MatchFound
    End Property

    Public Property Let RootFolder(ByRef inObject As Folder)
        Set this.RootFolder = inObject
    End Property
    Public Property Get RootFolder() As Folder
        Set RootFolder = this.RootFolder
    End Property

    Public Property Get MatchedFilePath() As String
        MatchedFilePath = this.MatchedFilePath
    End Property

    Public Sub AddTargetSubstring(ByVal inValue As String)

        With this

            If .StringsToMatch Is Nothing Then
                Set .StringsToMatch = New Dictionary
            End If
            .StringsToMatch.item(inValue) = inValue

        End With

    End Sub

    Public Sub ClearTargetSubstrings()

        Set this.StringsToMatch = Nothing

    End Sub

    Public Sub SearchFolderForMatch()

        With this

            .MatchFound = False
            .MatchedFilePath = vbNullString

            If .RootFolder Is Nothing Or .StringsToMatch Is Nothing Then
                PrintErrorMessage "Error: Target Folder Not Initialised or Target Substrings not supplied"
            Else
                RecurseFolderForMatch .RootFolder
            End If

        End With

    End Sub

    Private Sub RecurseFolderForMatch(ByRef folderToRecurse As Folder)
        '/ Search all filenames in the folder for a substring match
        '/ If there is no match, iterate sub-folders
        '/ For each subfolder, call RecurseFolderForMatch
        '/ Short-Circuit if This.MatchFound gets set to True

        Dim MatchFound As Boolean
        Dim iFile As File
        For Each iFile In folderToRecurse.Files

            MatchFound = NameContainsAnyTargetSubstring(iFile.name)

            If MatchFound Then
                this.MatchFound = True
                this.MatchedFilePath = iFile.Path
                GoTo EndRecursion
            End If

        Next iFile

        '/No file match found. Recurse Sub-folders
        Dim iFolder As Folder
        For Each iFolder In folderToRecurse.SubFolders

            If this.MatchFound = True Then
                GoTo EndRecursion '/ Short-Circuit if a sub-folder found a match
            End If

            RecurseFolderForMatch iFolder

        Next iFolder

EndRecursion:

    End Sub

    Public Function NameContainsAnyTargetSubstring(ByVal nameToCheck As String)

        Dim MatchFound As Boolean
        Dim key As Variant
        Dim stringToFind As String
        For Each key In this.StringsToMatch.Keys()
            stringToFind = CStr(key)
            MatchFound = (InStr(1, nameToCheck, stringToFind, vbTextCompare) > 0)
            If MatchFound Then
                GoTo EndCheck
            End If
        Next key

EndCheck:
        NameContainsAnyTargetSubstring = MatchFound

    End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Your example usage is needlessly complicated:

> ```
> Dim folderSearch As CLS_Search_Folder
> Set folderSearch = New CLS_Search_Folder
> With folderSearch
>     'do your thing
> End With
> ```

There's no need to even declare a local variable, just have the `With` block hold the reference instead:

```
With New CLS_Search_Folder
    'do your thing
End With
```

I don't like the `CLS` prefix and underscores in the class' name - I don't see a reason not to just call it `FolderSearch`:

```
With New FolderSearch
    'do your thing
End With
```

The VBE's *project explorer* already regroups modules by type, which means everything under the "Class Modules" folder will have that `CLS` prefix - what's the use then?

---

Whenever referring to early-bound types, it's usually a good idea to qualify them with the library they're from - e.g. `ADODB.Recordset`, `Scripting.Dictionary`, etc.

...unless you have Rubberduck's contextual status bar to spoil you with immediate knowledge of what's coming from where:

[image: RD contextual status bar]

Otherwise all you get is this when you try Shift+F2 / "go to definition":

[image: Identifier under the cursor is not recognized]

And only *then* you resort to the *object browser* to search for that `Folder` type in all referenced libraries.

---

Nitpick: I think the API / exposed members are too verbose, I would change `SearchFolderForMatch` to simply `Search`, or even `Execute`.

---

This doesn't look right:

```
Public Property Let RootFolder(ByRef inObject As Folder)
    Set this.RootFolder = inObject
End Property
```

It's an object reference, so it should be `Property Set`, not `Property Let` - and it *could* be passed by value still; it's just an object reference.

---

This is wrong:

```
PrintErrorMessage "Error: Target Folder Not Initialised or Target Substrings not supplied"
```

That's a dependency on an outside procedure, and the class itself shouldn't be responsible for *handling* such errors - that error should be bubbled up and handled by the client code, because it's not an error that the object is supposed to know how to handle - the object's job is to *search folders*, not print stuff to the debug output (or does that method log stuff in a database? or in a text file? or does it display a `MsgBox`?). Consider raising a custom error there.

---

Function `NameContainsAnyTargetSubstring` returns an implicit `Variant`; the signature should end with `As Boolean`.

It's also `Public`, but you're listing it as a *private method* in the OP. Glitch?

```
Dim MatchFound As Boolean
```

Avoid clashing names - you have `MatchFound` a member of the `SearchProperties` UDT already, so consider `MatchFound` taken as a public member's name. I'd go with `isFound`, or simply `result` here.

It's a bit off-putting and inconsistent that the public property backed by that `MatchFound` UDT member is called `FoundMatch`, given how every other property has the exact same name as its backing UDT member:

[image: FoundMatch != MatchFound]

---

There's no reason for `= True` here:

> ```
> If this.MatchFound = True Then
> ```

There are several spots where you have opted for an `If...End If` *block* when an `If...Then` *statement* would have been just fine - for example:

```
If this.MatchFound Then GoTo EndRecursion
```

Comment: Eh, I prefer to always put my `If`s in blocks, even when they could go on one, line. That way, when I see an `If`, I always know where to look to find out what it does.

Comment: Fair enough, but it doesn't excuse `= True` ;-)

Comment: Just the fully qualified early bound reference suggestion (`Scripting.Dictionary`) is enough for an up-vote.  This is actually a perfect example for why you should do this.  Drop the class in a Word document and you'll get a cryptic "Invalid use of New keyword" compiler error on `Set .StringsToMatch = New Dictionary` - `Dictionary` will default to `Word.Dictionary`, which isn't creatable...

Answer (score 2):

A couple things I noticed - all of your public methods rely on `this.StringsToMatch` being initialized.  You're using `Is Nothing` as basically a proxy for `.Count = 0`. Since the behavior of the class *depends* on having an initialized container, just create it once in `Class_Initialize`:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set this.StringsToMatch = New Scripting.Dictionary
End Sub
```

Then you can replace `ClearTargetSubstrings` with the much more natural...

```
Public Sub ClearTargetSubstrings()
    this.StringsToMatch.RemoveAll
End Sub
```

...and `.StringsToMatch Is Nothing` with the much clearer `.StringsToMatch.Count = 0`.

---

Along those same lines, I've always disliked the `Scripting.Dictionary` behavior of adding an item as a side-effect of calling `.Item(foo) = bar` if `foo` doesn't exist.  In my mind this should be an error, so it *looks like* an error at first glance.  Just because Microsoft made a bad implementation decision doesn't mean you have to rely on *their* poor implementation at the expense of *your* readability. If you always have a `.StringsToMatch` hanging around, you can make `AddTargetSubstring` a lot clearer as to what it is actually doing:

```
Public Sub AddTargetSubstring(ByVal inValue As String)
    With this.StringsToMatch
        If Not .Exists(inValue) Then
            .Add inValue, vbNull
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that this also allows you to add an additional dereference level to your `With` block.

---

Note above that I set the key, but left the item as `vbNull`. If the key and the item are always the same, there isn't any reason to store 2 copies of it.  You are basically using the `Scripting.Dictionary` as a simple hashset, so just use the part `.Keys()` that actually *is* the hashset. Save the memory and hassle of actually storing copies as the `.Item`.

---

I'll diverge a bit from @Mat'sMug's recommendation to have errors bubble up to the calling code.  The class is simple enough that I wouldn't even be raising errors about its state.  If you require that `this.RootFolder` is set, make the property read-only and make a `Scripting.Folder` a required parameter of `SearchFolderForMatch` instead. If you don't have any sub-strings to search, pick a default behavior (like returning `vbNullString` for `MatchedFilePath` or matching any file) and do that instead of raising an error.  That allows the calling code much more flexibility and removes the requirement for the caller to have to establish a valid object state before using certain (in this case 1) methods.

---

Short nit-pick break (and this is entirely a personal style preference) - I find the "out-dented" `GoTo` labels distracting. The vast, vast majority of code that I see has them simply pinned to the left margin where the VBE puts them.  Having them at a different indentation level makes think that they are acting as a closure, so it actually takes a bit of mental effort for me when I see this:

```
EndRecursion:

    End Sub

    Public Function NameContainsAnyTargetSubstring(ByVal nameToCheck As String)
       '...

EndCheck:
```

The fact that they all start with `End` makes it even worse. My brain does something like `End Sub`, `End Function`, `EndCheck`, ...WTF?

---

Finally, you have a pretty decent performance opportunity in `NameContainsAnyTargetSubstring`.  You are comparing every single file to the same set of keys, so I'd consider converting it to just build a RegExp pattern and using that instead.  Just getting rid of `files * substrings` extraneous string casts with the line `stringToFind = CStr(key)` is worth it alone.

I'd do something more like this.  Make `NameContainsAnyTargetSubstring` a simple wrapper function (mainly to avoid having to recreate the regex pattern repeatedly):

```
'Class level variable.
'Requires reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
Private substringRegex As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp 

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set this.StringsToMatch = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set substringRegex = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    substringRegex.IgnoreCase = True
End Sub
```

...and down below:

```
Private Sub SetRegexPattern()
    substringRegex.Pattern = "(" & Join(this.StringsToMatch.Keys, ")|(") & ")"
End Sub

Public Function NameContainsAnyTargetSubstring(ByVal nameToCheck As String) As Boolean
    If this.StringsToMatch.Count = 0 Then Exit Function 'Or whatever default.
    SetRegexPattern
    NameContainsAnyTargetSubstring = substringRegex.Test(nameToCheck)
End Function

Private Sub RecurseFolderForMatch(ByRef folderToRecurse As Folder)
    SetRegexPattern

    Dim candidate As File
    For Each candidate In folderToRecurse.Files
        With candidate
            this.MatchFound = substringRegex.Test(.Name)
            If this.MatchFound Then
                this.MatchedFilePath = .Path
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
    Next

    Dim subFolder As Folder
    For Each subFolder In folderToRecurse.SubFolders
        RecurseFolderForMatch subFolder
        If this.MatchFound = True Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

<sup>You can probably just leave the VBScript_RegExp_55 off the declaration of RegExp - pedantic mode was on solely to avoid the [appearance of hypocracy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140861/recursive-directory-searching-for-filenames#comment263911_140868).</sup>